# Are C-[0-9] and M-[0-9] completely interchangeable?

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode, minor-mode

In all my exploration, it seems that M-[0-9] and C-[0-9] apply numeric prefixes in the same way everywhere. Does this change for any common modes? I'm considering overwriting one of the sets of bindings (because they're accessible bindings), but I'm always so tentative to step on the toes of the default bindings. I'm reaching out to this wonderful community to see if you know of any areas where I'll regret this overwrite.

I include the major-mode and minor-mode tags because I'm wary of how these bindings will be altered by popular modes and packages I may not have yet explored. It's easy enough to see that they work similarly in the starting buffer, but I'm curious about the rest of the popular parts of the ecosystem.

I'm particularly focused on these bindings because they are very quick with my keyboard. I'm a QMK user, and my keyboard layout makes M-[0-9] much faster than dealing with even a single prefix.

Comment: In general, you *should* be wary of changing these things: they make your emacs incompatible with just about everybody else's emacs (which might or might not make a difference to you). There is a whole class of keybindings that are specifically reserved for users (`C-c <letter>` and function keys `<F5>-<F9>` without modifiers - see [Key Binding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Conventions.html)). Defining some to be prefix keys vastly increases the number of keybindings available at the cost of one extra keystroke.

Comment: The question is unclear: *"I'm considering overwriting one of the sets of bindings"*. Overriding in the global map or in some local (major-mode) map, or in some minor-mode map, or on some text (text-property `keymap`)?

Comment: Those keys are essentially the same in the `global-map`. They might not be the same in other keymaps, which override the `global-map` in various situations. Are you asking only about overriding keys in the `global-map`? You included tags `major-mode` and `minor-mode` - why? Please consider clarifying your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I do `C-h k M-1`, I  get

`M-1` runs the command digit-argument (found in `global-map`), which is an
interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.

It is bound to

`C-9`, `C-8`, `C-7`, `C-6`, `C-5`, `C-4`, `C-3`, `C-2`, `C-1`, `C-0`,
`ESC 0..9`,

`C-M-9`, `C-M-8`, `C-M-7`, `C-M-6`, `C-M-5`, `C-M-4`, `C-M-3`, `C-M-2`, `C-M-1`and `C-M-0`.

```lisp
(digit-argument ARG)
```

Part of the numeric argument for the next command. `C-u` following digits or minus sign ends the argument.

---

When I do `C-h w digit-argument`, you get

`digit-argument` is on

`C-9`, `C-8`, `C-7`, `C-6`, `C-5`, `C-4`, `C-3`, `C-2`, `C-1`, `C-0`,`ESC 0..9`,`C-M-9`, `C-M-8`, `C-M-7`, `C-M-6`, `C-M-5`, `C-M-4`, `C-M-3`, `C-M-2`, `C-M-1`, `C-M-0`

---

Whenever there is a multiple key binding for the same command, it is usually to accommodate `emacs -nw` (terminal `emacs`) users.

Try running `C-h k C-1` etc, `C-h k M-1` etc, and `C-h k C-M-1` etc on a `emacs -nw` and see what you get.

The `C-1`...`C-9`, `M-1...M-9`, `C-M-1...C-M-9` are convenient ways to get single decimal digits.

And you can always input digit arguments using `C-u 123` etc..  So yes, you can override the above  keys.

I do have plenty of key bindings on the numeric keys.

---

For the sake of completion, this is what `C-h k C-u` shows

`C-u` runs the command `universal-argument` (found in `global-map`), which
is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.

It is bound to `C-u`.

(`universal-argument`)

Begin a numeric argument for the following command.

Digits or minus sign following `C-u` make up the numeric argument.

`C-u` following the digits or minus sign ends the argument.

`C-u` without digits or minus sign provides 4 as argument.

Repeating `C-u` without digits or minus sign multiplies the argument by 4 each time.

For some commands, just `C-u` by itself serves as a flag
that is different in effect from any particular numeric argument.

These commands include `C-SPC` and `M-x start-kbd-macro`.

---

Following the leads in

- [Define your  own `BLAH` / `fake` keys (so that they are not hijacked by other modules)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/73890/31220)
- [Three bonus keys—`C-i`, `C-m` and `C-\[`—for your GUI Emacs; all with zero headache](https://emacsnotes.wordpress.com/2022/09/11/three-bonus-keys-c-i-c-m-and-c-for-your-gui-emacs-all-with-zero-headache/)

Here is an "attempt" to get more *BONUS* keys  ... The snippet is  works on GUI Emacs.

```lisp
(cl-loop for (x . fmt-string) in
         `(
           ;; ????: The `C-xxx` keys are problematic to generate in
           ;; terminal.  If you type it, `Emacs` may report a
           ;; different thing.  The behaviour varies with the
           ;; terminal.
           ("C" . "C-%s")
           ("M" . "M-%s")
           ;; ????: The previous comment applies
           ("C-M" . "C-M-%s")
           ,@(when (display-graphic-p)
               '(("ESCAPE" . "<escape> %s"))))
         do (cl-loop for digit in (number-sequence 0 9)
                     for key = (format fmt-string digit)
                     for sym = (intern (format "BLAH-%s-%s" x digit))
                     do (condition-case err
                            (progn
                              (message "%s -> %s" key sym)
                              (define-key input-decode-map (kbd key) (vector sym)))
                          (error (message "Error %S" err)))))

;; Bind `C-1' to `find-file'
(global-set-key (kbd "<BLAH-C-1> f") 'find-file)

(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'outline-minor-mode)

;; Bind `C-0' as `outline-minor-mode-prefix'
(custom-set-variables
 ;; Key zero look like `o` (for outline)
 '(outline-minor-mode-prefix (kbd "<BLAH-C-0>")))

;; Use `C-0 C-0' to to enable `outline-minor-mode'
(global-set-key (kbd "<BLAH-C-0> <BLAH-C-0>") 'outline-minor-mode)

(add-hook 'hs-minor-mode-hook
          (defun my-hs-minor-mode-hook ()
            ;; Overwrite `hs-minor-mode-map'. `C-c @' is difficult to
            ;; type.
            (setq hs-minor-mode-map
                  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
                    ;; These bindings roughly imitate those used by Outline mode.
                    (define-key map (kbd "C-S-b") 'hs-show-block)
                    (define-key map (kbd "C-b") 'hs-hide-block)
                    (define-key map (kbd "C-a") 'hs-hide-all)
                    (define-key map (kbd "C-S-a") 'hs-show-all)
                    (define-key map (kbd "C-l") 'hs-hide-level)
                    (define-key map (kbd "C-c") 'hs-toggle-hiding)
                    (define-key map (kbd "<BLAH-C-2>") 'hs-minor-mode)
                    map))
            ;; Put `hs-' commands on `C-2' prefix;
            ;; 2 and `@' are on the same key on the keyboard.
            (fset 'hs-minor-mode-map hs-minor-mode-map)
            (global-set-key (kbd "<BLAH-C-2>") 'hs-minor-mode-map)))

;; Use `C-2 C-2' to toggle `hs-minor-mode'
(global-set-key (kbd "<BLAH-C-2> <BLAH-C-2>") 'hs-minor-mode)
```

---

Apropos the remark *"some `C-xxx` keys are problematic to generate in terminal"* in the snippet above,

- On `gnome-terminal`, with `emacs -Q -nw`, when I do `C-h k C-1`, `Emacs` says

  ```
  1 runs the command self-insert-command (found in global-map)
  ```
- On `xterm`, with `emacs -Q` when I do `C-h k C-2`, `Emacs` says

  ```
  C-@ runs the command set-mark-command (found in global-map)
  ```

Similar observations can be made for "some"(?) `C-M-xxx` bindings.  `C-M-xxx` is essentially `M-` and `C-xxx` and `M-` is emitted with `ESC` and if you have issues with `C-xxx` it shouldn't be surprising that there are issues with `C-M-xxx`.

[Comprehensive keyboard handling in terminals](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/keyboard-protocol/) is a good introduction to terminals, and with a quick glimpse one can reasonably anticipate which key sequences are going to give you problematic on the terminal `Emacs`.

*I understand none of what I say, so take what I say with a grain of salt.  But the behavioural observations I make can be independently verified.  I am on Debian / sid, btw.*

Comment: I use -nw, actually (so it was very easy to test your suggestion). The outcome of C-[0-9] and M-[0-9] is the same on -nw. Thanks.

Comment: With `emacs -Q -nw`,  on `gnome-terminal`  when I do `C-h k C-1`, I actually see that `Emacs` is receiving `1 runs the command self-insert-command (found in global-map)`, and on `xterm` when I do `C-h k C-2`, `Emacs` is reporting `C-@ runs the command set-mark-command (found in global-map)`.  **I am VERY SURPRISED that you are able to actually enter those key sequences, and `Emacs` is reporting the key sequences you typed (instead of picking its own).**  I expect you to see surprises.

Comment: Btw, [Comprehensive keyboard handling in terminals](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/keyboard-protocol/) is a good introduction to terminals, and with a quick glimpse at that you can reasonably anticipate which key sequences are going to give you surprises.

Comment: I have made some more snippets ... since we last talked.

Comment: My config is definitely not "emacs -q -nw". I use the term-keys package and a fleshed-out Alacritty config. That being said, I'm able to basically replicate the GUI behavior with the terminal. Thanks for pointing out the bonus keys. I hadn't even really though about taking advantage of C-i, C-m, etc., but they really are prime real estate (and I think I can get around the terminal limitations with my configuration).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the bindings myself, I'd say go ahead and adjust the bindings to your liking. Even if you're overwriting some default binding, if you never use it, why not adjust it a way that's most convenient for you?
If you plan on sharing your changes with the public, that's another story of course. :-)